# Aplicando o JS para Validar Input com OnBlur

Tags: javascript

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
<script>
function TestaCPF(strCPF) {
    var Soma;
    var Resto;
    Soma = 0;
    if (strCPF == "00000000000") return false;

    for (i=1; i<=9; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(strCPF.substring(i-1, i)) * (11 - i);
    Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;

    if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11))  Resto = 0;
    if (Resto != parseInt(strCPF.substring(9, 10)) ) return false;

    Soma = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(strCPF.substring(i-1, i)) * (12 - i);
    Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;

    if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11))  Resto = 0;
    if (Resto != parseInt(strCPF.substring(10, 11) ) ) return false;
    return true;
}
var strCPF = "12345678909";
alert(TestaCPF(strCPF));
</script>
```

Ele está validando o CPF, eu gostaria de saber como aplico em um Input...
Ex: Validou? O campo fica verde... Não validou? Vermelho.
Sei que tenho que usar o OnBlur no campo, mas ainda estou em duvida de como usar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta chamar a função a partir do evento `onblur` do `input`, como parâmetro você pode passar o próprio `elemento`/`input`, com isso para alterar a cor fica mais fácil.

Da seguinte forma:

```js
function TestaCPF(elemento) {
  cpf = elemento.value;
  cpf = cpf.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
  if (cpf == '') return elemento.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  // Elimina CPFs invalidos conhecidos    
  if (cpf.length != 11 ||
    cpf == "00000000000" ||
    cpf == "11111111111" ||
    cpf == "22222222222" ||
    cpf == "33333333333" ||
    cpf == "44444444444" ||
    cpf == "55555555555" ||
    cpf == "66666666666" ||
    cpf == "77777777777" ||
    cpf == "88888888888" ||
    cpf == "99999999999")
    return elemento.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  // Valida 1o digito 
  add = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    add += parseInt(cpf.charAt(i)) * (10 - i);
  rev = 11 - (add % 11);
  if (rev == 10 || rev == 11)
    rev = 0;
  if (rev != parseInt(cpf.charAt(9)))
    return elemento.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  // Valida 2o digito 
  add = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    add += parseInt(cpf.charAt(i)) * (11 - i);
  rev = 11 - (add % 11);
  if (rev == 10 || rev == 11)
    rev = 0;
  if (rev != parseInt(cpf.charAt(10)))
   return elemento.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  return elemento.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="TestaCPF(this)">
```

---

Detalhe, alterei sua função de verificação de cpf pra uma outra que esta disponível em: http://www.geradorcpf.com/javascript-validar-cpf.htm porque não consegui entender seu código de verificação. Mas deve funcionar do mesmo modo se você alterar seu código nos locais onde tem o `return false` ou `true` por `return elemento.style.backgroundColor = "red/blue";`

Answer (score 0):

Deve funcionar assim:

```
<input type="text" id="seu_texto" onblur="TestaCPF(this.value);" />
```